# Get-ADUser where custom attribute IS null

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to query AD for user who have custom extensionAttribute10 not set OR not equal to specific value. I successfuly get the users with value not equal to 100 with that command:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=OU1,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=local" -filter 'extensionAttribute10 -ne "100"'
```

What should I add to get also those with the value ?
I've tried diffrent ways but nothing worked.

Please help

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Can you go into more detail regarding how you know it is not working? Are you getting users back that have an ExtensionAttribute10 value of "100"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get users where an attribute is not set, you'd use `-notlike "*"`. Use `-or` to combine that with the filter you already have:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=OU1,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=local" -filter 'extensionAttribute10 -ne "100" -or extensionAttribute10 -notlike "*"'
```

Comment: @IGORLEVKOVSKY - If this works, please select this answer by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=OU1,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=local"
-Properties * | ? {$_.extensionAttribute10 -eq $null -or $_.extensionAttribute10 -eq 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

use where-object or ? take long time

for me help

```
get-aduser -filter {-not(extensionAttribute15 -like "*")}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).